# Dynamically render a component inside a another component in React

Tags: reactjs, render

I tried to dynamically pass a reference to a class to a container and render it.

```
    class Test extends React.Component{
        render() {
           return <div>Test</div>
        }
    }

    class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
           constructor(props) {
              super(props);

              this.state = {
                  child: Test
              };
           }

           render() {
               return <div>{this.state.child}</div>;
          }
    }

    React.render(<HelloWidget />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

See it at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/coolshare/jwm6k66c/2720/

It did not render anything...

Any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `React.createElement` to create the new react element.

Like this:

```
render() {
    return <div>hello {React.createElement(this.state.child)}</div>;
}
```

Check the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzv254br/).

Comment: @MarkQian If you find the answer useful please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically change the state value in HelloWidget component and that would reflect in Test Component.
Here is the code:

```
    class Test extends React.Component{

            render() {
        return <div>{this.props.child}</div>
    }
        }
  class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
            child: "Test"
      };
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <Test child={this.state.child}/>
        </div>;
    }
  }

  React.render(<HelloWidget />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is a working fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jayesh24/1uvpg5ej/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Directive of your Test inside the constructor to create that component when you are assigning

```
      this.state = {
            child: <Test />
      };
```